# Разная длительность кадров в покадровой анимации Unity

Tags: unity3d, анимация

Создаю игру под **android**.

Нарисовал анимацию в Photoshop, и выставил для кадров нужную длительность проигрывания (таким образом, не нужно рисовать или копировать один и тот же кадр).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но в Unity я не нашел подобной настройки для разной длительности воспроизведения кадров.

Я, конечно, могу сохранить анимацию как последовательность кадров определенной частоты, но тогда будет очень много одинаковых кадров, которые сожрут кучу памяти и раздуют apk. Хотелось бы избежать этого.

Возможно я что то упускаю? Подскажите, пожалуйста, есть ли в Unity подобные возможности?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как я понимаю, вам нужно следующее:

Когда делаете анимацию (выбираете `Window` → `Animation`), то каждый спрайт в линейке анимации можно перетаскивать на любое расстояние вдоль временной шкалы:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Просто берете и ставите спрайты пореже...там, где посчитаете нужным